# Centering UIImageView in UItableViewCell doesn't work, how to fix?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I can subclass the cell and resolve the problem, but I'd like to know why this doesn't work.

I set an image in the cell, then in this method, I move the image to the right:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2 - cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2 + 100,
                                            cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2 - cell.imageView.frame.size.height/2,
                                            cell.imageView.frame.size.width,
                                            cell.imageView.frame.size.height)];
        NSLog(@"center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cell.imageView.center));
        NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.imageView.frame));
}
```

Notice the +100 I added to ensure it's over to the right.

When I check the console, it indicates this:

center: {250, 57.5}

frame: {{150, 7.5}, {200, 100}}

However the output is this:

[image: grouped cell image]

The image is still aligned to the left side.  Can this be changed, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you go to the header file of UITableViewCell than there you will find...

```
> // Content.  These properties provide direct access to the internal
> label and image views used by the table view cell.  These should be
> used instead of the content properties below.
> @property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UIImageView  *imageView
> __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);   // default is nil.  image view will be created if necessary.
```

so as you can see it says readOnly property to the image view... I think this explains your inability to move the imageView.

Answer (score 1):

You can not move the image view. Solution is or to subclass and do your own drawing in drawRect, or to add a subview to the cell.contentView.

Edit:

> If an image is set, it appears on the left side of the cell, before
>   any label. UITableViewCell creates the image-view object when you
>   create the cell.

From [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView)

Comment: Can you point out where this is confirmed in the docs?  I've searched all over and can't find anything on it.